# Unable to access scriplet variable in my javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, scriptlet

Iam trying to access a scriplet variable in my javascript function,but i am not getting resul as expected,
here is my javascript,

```
<script language="javascript">
function drawFreeSlot(){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
     var slotNo = <%=slotCount%>;
    div.className = 'col-1';
    //div.appendChild("Slot"+slotNo);
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
</script>
```

and my scriplet code as ,

```
<%!int slotCount = 0; %>
<%for(ParkingSlot slot:slotList){
 if(slot.getPhoneNo() == 0){
 slotCount++;%>
 <script>
 drawFreeSlot();

 </script>
<%
 }%>
```

both code are in same jsp file,
Please help me,Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to think about how the JSP code is rendered. If you view the page source in your browser you'll probably see what's happening: assuming `drawFreeSlot()` is defined once, it will have `var slotNo` set to whatever `<%=slotCount%>` was at that point, it won't magically update just because you have a JSP loop outputting multiple calls to `drawFreeSlot()`.

Comment: When loop iterates ,the slotCount variable takes new values,then in my javascript code i can access that value only right>

Comment: you are right nnnnnn,but my slotCount is always 0..can you tell me y?

Comment: When the JavaScript runs in the browser *it can't see Java variables*, it can only see whatever the Java output before the response was sent to the browser. All Java code (including your loop) is executed server-side before any JS code runs in the browser. A quick fix for your problem would be to change the JS function to `function drawFreeSlot(slotNo)` and then in the other code call it with `drawFreeSlot(<%=slotCount%>)`.

Comment: thanks man..i was trying drawFreeSlot(slotCount) only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand your problem, you need some informations on the way this is done.

Your are working with two different side in your code. The scriplet on the server side and the javascript on client side, First the scriplet is executed then the result is send to the browser to execute the javascript.

**Server side**

The first thing to understand is that the Scriplet will not execute Javascript code. The JSP will basicly add some text into the file.

In your case, your loop will insert

```
<script>
    drawFreeSlot();
</script>
```

For each ParkingSlot with a phone number at 0. (and increment the variable).

It will also insert the **variable value** into the function

```
<script language="javascript">
function drawFreeSlot(){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
     var slotNo = <%=slotCount%>;
    div.className = 'col-1';
    //div.appendChild("Slot"+slotNo);
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
</script>
```

The values will depend on the position of this code, if this is after the loop, you will have the number of slot, if not, it will be 0. It doesn't use the variable, just insert the value as text.

**Client side**

When this is done, the page will be send to the Client browser and receive an HTML page with a those script block.

The browser will read the file to show the result. This is when the Javascript is execute. So for each `drawFreeSlot()` block found, he will execute the function, but the function only have the value of the variable insert at the time, this is where is your problem.

**Solution**

As **nnnnnn** suggest it,passing using a parameter will fix the problem.

```
<script>drawFreeSlot(<%=++slotCount%>);</script>
```

The HTML page will look like :

```
...
<script>
    drawFreeSlot(1);
</script>
...
<script>
    drawFreeSlot(2);
</script>
...
<script>
    drawFreeSlot(3);
</script>
...
```

Just a simple change in the function to work with this parameter is need and your code will work.

Since on each loop, you print the value at this time of your variable.

Answer (score 0):

As nnnnnn pointed out, `var slotNo = <%=slotCount%>` will set `slotNo` only one time and then it will not be updated as you expect.
Instead, pass an argument to the function, so that the value of `slotCount` in function scope will be dependent on each function call.

```
function drawFreeSlot(slotCount) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'col-1';
  div.appendChild("Slot" + slotCount);
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
  var sc = slotCount;
}
```

**Solution 1**: will not refresh `slotCount` on each new request

```
<%!
   int slotCount = 0;
   List<String> mylist = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "ABC", "DEF");
%>
<%
  for (String str: mylist) {
    if(str.length() < 3) { %>
      <script>drawFreeSlot(<%=++slotCount%>);</script>
<%  }
  } %>
```

**Solution 2**: use JSTL (will refresh `slotCount` on each new request)

```
<% request.setAttribute("mylist", mylist); %>
<c:set var="slotCount" value="0"/>
<c:forEach var="str" items="${mylist}">
  <c:if test="${str.length() < 3}">
    <c:set var="slotCount" value="${slotCount+1}"/>
    <script>drawFreeSlot(${slotCount});</script>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Replace my stub list and condition statement with yours and it should work.